# Redirect Subdomain Using htaccess and Keep URL

Tags: security, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, subdomain

I have searched and while I found lots of threads close, none were exactly what I am looking for...

On my site, say example.com, I've created the subdomain secure.example.com

This subdomain will have SSL.

What I want to do is redirect requests to https://secure.example.com/path/ to www.example.com/path/ while keeping the url showing as https://secure.example.com/path/

note that the purpose of subdomain.example.com is for SSL so the redirect above will need to work with SSL

I would like to use a few other redirects in the htaccess:
1) redirect non-www to www ignoring subdomains (so secure.example.com doesn't become www.secure.example.com)
2) redirect /index.php to /
3) and last but not least, force SSL on secure.example.com

In addition the shopping cart software has additional htaccess statements for functionality and SEO as seen below.

### My current root htaccess:

```
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine On

## index.php to root
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L] 

## non-www to www ignore subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Are both `example.com` and `secure.example.com` on the same host and the same document root? Do you have mod_proxy loaded?

Comment: Yes they are on the same host and same document root. The subdomain is literally a subfolder under the root setup with a subdomain. With help from my host we now have it resolving properly and the SSL installed.

Comment: The only thing left is the redirect as in my original post.As for mod_proxy, I don't know but I'm betting it's not installed. I sent a ticket to my host to find out for sure.

Comment: My host says that mod_proxy is installed. My Apache config shows these are installed:

proxy_module (static)
proxy_connect_module (static)
proxy_ftp_module (static)
proxy_http_module (static)
proxy_ajp_module (static)
proxy_balancer_module (static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, specifically for the url `https://secure.example.com/path/` to display content found at `http://www.example.com/path/`, there's 2 things that you can do. The best thing is if the 2 domains are served from the same document root:

> they are on the same host and same document root. The subdomain is literally a subfolder under the root setup with a subdomain. With help from my host we now have it resolving properly and the SSL installed.

The subdirectory might be a problem, since it may not be able to rewrite *out* of its own document root. For example:

- **domain** -> document root
- **www.example.com** -> /path/to/htdocs
- **secure.example.com** -> /path/to/htdocs/secure

If you had an .htaccess file in `/path/to/htdocs/secure` to rewrite requests for `https://secure.example.com/`. The problem here is you need to rewrite to the parent directory, and apache won't let you do that. If it was the other way around, you could rewrite requests for `http://www.example.com/` to `/secure`. Also, if the two domains had the same document root, you could also rewrite. But not if secure is a subdirectory to www's document root.

> My host says that mod_proxy is installed. My Apache config shows these are installed: proxy_module (static) proxy_connect_module (static) proxy_ftp_module (static) proxy_http_module (static) proxy_ajp_module (static) proxy_balancer_module (static)

That means you can at least use the `P` rewrite flag to send the request off to mod_proxy, so you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^path/$ http://www.example.com/path/ [L,P]
```

in the htaccess file in your secure.example.com's document root. That will only proxy specifically the URI `/path/`, and not anything like `/path/foo/bar.html`. If you want everything starting with `/path/`, then you can match against it:

```
RewriteRule ^path/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/path/$1 [L,P]
```

---

If there are redirection issues, you may want to resort to using `ProxyPass` instead:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/
```

It does the same thing except it rewrites location headers so redirects also get proxied.

Comment: Thanks. I tried (both SSL and non) and got nothing. I'm still seeing my test file in secure.example.com, and not the one at example.com
Looking at your post I just realized something, I didn't mean that "path" would be there literally, I used path as whatever comes after secure.example.com

Comment: @Bob You can just remote the `path/` from both the regex and the target of those `RewriteRule`'s then.

Comment: I removed 'path/' and now it partly works.
SSL is warning that the pages are only partially encrypted. The certificate belongs to secure.example.com
And links on the page that point to the actual domain (www.example.com) are returning 404s.

Comment: The 404s are gone. The root htaccess was causing this. But the partially secure warnings remain.

Comment: @Bob That may be caused by links in the *www.example.com* domain using FQDN's, like: `<img src=http://www.example.com/images/foo.jpg>`, which would raise that warning.

Comment: I just checked and they actually have both standard http and SSL defines for images in the php config file. I would think this wouldn't be an issue. More than anything, if I open in IE it's obvious the stylesheet isn't loading. 

Man soooo close but still no cigar...

Comment: @Bob you just need to remove the FQDN's from links, also see my edit, it may be a redirect issue.

Comment: Here's a virtual beer or coke or whatever you like. You've been fantastic and I really appreciate all the help. 
After disabling a banner on the site it is now loading both http and https correctly from both the domain and subdomain, and fully SSL in firefox, chrome and IE. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Bob I wonder what was in the banner that prevented all this from working. If the answer was helpful [make sure you accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171219) so that your question gets marked as resolved and other people with a similar question will know this one had a resolution.

Comment: I'm new to stack. Is there some way I can give you points, reps or something like that?

Comment: the banner is loaded from it's own little script within the cart, as is every other part of the cart. I haven't had a chance to look at it yet, but I'm guessing I'll be able to get it back with a little work. There are still a few errors here and there, like when I click a product image to display the product description page the entire site goes ssl and I get the partially encrypted warning, but these are all minor things that can be dug into and worked out. 
Just so you know, it has literally been 36 hours that I was working on the redirect, with nothing working until your help. Thank you.