# How to redirect 'page.php' to 'index.php?page='

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect, using `.htaccess`, the call for `page.php?id=` to `index.php?page=` but keep the url in the user's browser `page.php?id=`? I think wordpress uses this.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959853/redirect-subdomain-using-htaccess-and-keep-url

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you use the wordpress `.htaccess`?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit:**

And in `index.php`:

```
<?php 

$id = 1;
if ($_GET['id'] and @intval($_GET['id']))
    $id = $_GET['id'];

echo 'Current id: ' . $id;
```

When you visit `page.php?id=4` the output is `Current id: 4`. Wordpress does not use redirects. It simply rewrites all urls to `index.php` and this script includes all necessary files.

Comment: This just removes the index.php from `index.php?page=` and leaves me with `?page=`.