# Redirecting links

Tags: url, redirect, hyperlink

I'm aware of the concept of using a url re-redirect so that 2 urls map to the same page.  Is there anyway to keep the url cosmetically the same?  In other words, a user goes to:

http://www.sitename.com/pagename.php

but they get redirected to:

http://www.anothersite.com/pagename.php

where the user still sees in their window:

http://www.sitename.com/pagename.php

Comment: That would be changing the browser which you cannot do....

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  If it's browser related, couldn't I use javascript?

Comment: I think you can accomplish that by using an iframe.

Comment: Hmmmm...I'm actually trying to change how the address bar itself looks and am not quite sure how an iframe could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post [Redirect Subdomain Using htaccess and Keep URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959853/redirect-subdomain-using-htaccess-and-keep-url)

What you would want to investigate is .htaccess and mod_proxy()

You could also copy the contents with PHP with

file_get_contents("http://www.anothersite.com/pagename.php");

and print this out on sitename.com

Comment: Cool! Both approaches have given me some new direction.